# iconv to convert Mainframe EBCDIC file to Unix readable format writes data in one single row

Tags: unix, mainframe, file-format, iconv, ebcdic

I am trying to convert Mainframe file to Unix readable format using below iconv command.
iconv -f IBM-037 -t ISO8859-1 FileA > FileB

This command converts data as expected, but writes output data in one single row.
Can someone help on how to handle this file format conversion?

Comment: Is your "Mainframe file" a z/OS dataset or a z/Unix file?  Are you running iconv on the mainframe?

Answer (score 3):

@Steve Ives, you can do this in one step, eliminating the intermediate file, and a couple of I/Os.

In z/OS UNIX, the `cp` utility can read and write (unix) files as well as (MVS) data sets. With this in mind, your job can be done as follows:

```
//CONVERT  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=8M                                    
//STDERR   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                  
//STDOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                  
//STEPLIB  DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=SYS1.CEE.SCEERUN                             
//*                                                                       
//STDPARM  DD   *                                                         
sh /bin/cp -T -O c=iso8859-1 
   "//'P.OPS.CA7GRAPH.MCAWKLY.REPORT'"
   /u/jocs065/ihsconfig/ihs/jocs065/cgi-bin/phpNoSecure/MCAWKLY.txt         
/*
```

*Note* that `cp` silently assumes the source code page is IBM-1047. This cannot be changed. But in your case this is fine.

Comment: Thanks - I'd been struggling with a simple, reliable conversion and got my solution from IBM after raising a PMR.

Comment: A few of the z/OS UNIX utilities officially support reading or writing from or to MVS data sets, resp. Those that do havie it documented in the manual or man pages. They are safe to use for productive matters.Some other utilities *seem* to support as well, but the doc doesn't mention it. ```cat``` being one example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you transfer the data in *binary* from z/OS to UNIX, then use `iconv` on the UNIX side. There are no line end characters on z/OS *data set records*, so there is nothing in the data that iconv can convert to line end character(s).

You need to transfer in *ASCII*. FTP will take care of the translation, *and* will insert line end character(s).

You can set influence the code pages used in translating, if the default set on the FTP server on z/OS is not what you need:

```
quote site sbdataconn=(*host-code-page*,*network-(unix)-code-page*)
```

Default line end characters are 0x0d0a. You can change this with

```
quote site sbsendeol=NL
                     CR
                     CRLF  (default)
                     NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, a z/OS file has no CR or LF characters in it.

I have an application where I need a z/OS file processed by a PHP program, so I copy the file from z/OS to USS using the USS `OCOPY` command in batch:

```
//COPYMCA  EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01                                            
//*                                                                     
//MVS    DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=P.OPS.CA7GRAPH.MCAWKLY.REPORT    MCA Data     
//*                                                                     
//HFS    DD PATH='/u/jocs065/ihsconfig/ihs/jocs065/cgi-bin/phpNoSecure/ 
//             MCAWKLY_EBC.txt',                                        
//          PATHDISP=(KEEP,DELETE),                                     
//          PATHOPTS=(OWRONLY,OCREAT), Add OEXCL to fail if exists      
//          PATHMODE=(SIRUSR,SIWUSR,SIROTH)                             
//*        
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  
//SYSTSIN  DD *                                                         
OCOPY INDD(MVS) OUTDD(HFS) TEXT CONVERT((BPXFX000))
```

and then a second step which runs `iconv` to do the code page conversion:

```
//*  Convert USS file to correct character set.                            
//CONVERT  EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,REGION=8M                                    
//STDERR   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                  
//STDOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                  
//STEPLIB  DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=SYS1.CEE.SCEERUN                             
//*                                                                       
//STDPARM  DD   *                                                         
sh /bin/iconv -f IBM-1047 -t ISO8859-1                                    
 /u/jocs065/ihsconfig/ihs/jocs065/cgi-bin/phpNoSecure/MCAWKLY_EBC.txt >   
 /u/jocs065/ihsconfig/ihs/jocs065/cgi-bin/phpNoSecure/MCAWKLY.txt         
//*
```

Comment: "As previously answered, a z/OS file has no CR or LF characters in it." No, z/OS (UNIX) *text files* do have line end characters (0x0A), but z/OS (MVS) data sets do not. Picky? maybe, but it helps to clarify what you're talking about, especially when you have both in context, as in yoyur example. No offence intended, just a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe - I’m just used to people referring to z/OS or MVS files/datasets one the one side and USS files on the other side. I don’t recall anyone ever referring to a file in the USS environment as a z/OS file.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following technique to perform iconv on a z/OS data set:

cat "//'MY.MVS.DATA.SET'" | iconv -f IBM-273 -t UTF-8 > ./my.unix.file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).